# Leaflet with D3 polylines

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet

Is it possible to use D3 for polylines in Leaflet?

What I am trying to achieve is a less accurate, but more stylised, route display.  I'd like to use d3's interpolation('monotone') on a line (or path) which runs through each marker point in Leaflet and creates a smooth, curved line.

The only example I have found close to this is http://erasmus.ahoi.in which creates nice smooth arcs using d3 and canvas.

Does anyone know of any examples of this?

I have created a fiddle with some markers on a Leaflet map in case someone wants to give it a shot: http://fiddle.jshell.net/zw8TR/10/

Comment: Follow up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21212870

Answer (score 2):

Mike Bostock (the creator of D3) has written a nice tutorial on how to use D3 in combination with Leaflet. He uses GeoJSON polygons in his example but they can easily be swapped with GeoJSON linestrings, which you would be needing.

See: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/leaflet/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have looked at that link before, but hadn't actually appreciated what he was doing in terms of hooking up d3 and Leaflet.  After alot of hair pulling I've realised that I need properly learn what geojson is and does!  That Mike Bostock is a smart cookie!