# Using d3 in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet

This is a follow up question to [my other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20897985).

http://fiddle.jshell.net/zw8TR/16/

I have managed to utilise d3 to visualise the route between my map markers.  I used [this example](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/leaflet/) by Mike Bostock as guidance.

The reason I'm using d3 for this instead of Leaflets built in Polyline, is because I'd like to experiment with d3's interpolation to smooth out some routes, and also create arc's for others (for flight routes).  **At this stage though, I'm just trying to find a way to get these to work for all routes.**

The examples I've seen only use the `interpolate()` method with `d3.svg.line()`, whereas the Leaflet integration requires me to use `d3.geo.path()`.  Is there a place in my code where it's possible to use this method with `d3.geo.path()`?

Another possibly [helpful link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/MLZX1AbS7-Y).

And [another](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5851933).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing this is a bit messier than using `d3.geo.path` because that already implements all the boilerplate functionality you need for maps, but it's certainly possible. The idea is to extract the list of user coordinates from the geo path and translate them to screen coordinates in the `line` function. This translation can be done in the `.x()` and `.y()` functions of the line.

```
var path1 = d3.svg.line()
        .interpolate("cardinal")
        .x(function(d) { return map.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(d[1], d[0])).x; })
        .y(function(d) { return map.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(d[1], d[0])).y; });
```

Now we just need to extract the coordinates from the feature.

```
feature.attr("d", function(d) { return path1(d.geometry.coordinates); });
```

Complete example [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/zw8TR/17/).

Comment: Thanks again Lars.  It should be much easier for me to implement other d3 features when using `d3.svg.line()` instead of `d3.geo.path()`.  Perfect!